# Como removo mongodb.so do PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

Há algum tempo atrás instalei o Mongo DB numa máquina virtual para testar. Também instalei a biblioteca do PHP para manipulação do banco. Até aí tudo bem. Acontece que depois disso não consigo mais usar o composer. Sempre dá o erro abaixo:

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/mongodb.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/mongodb.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Localize seu *php.ini* (utilize o comando `php -i` ou o código `phpinfo();`) e remova ou adicione `;` (no início) da linha que contém *mongodb.so*.

Comment: Esse erro e porque a biblioteca do mongo db não existe, você pode fazer o que o nosso amigo @ValdeirPsr falou e ou também tentar instalar a biblioteca.